# How to find the function range of this?

Tags: functions, function-construction

How can I function range of the function `x/(-1 + 2 x)` over the domain `(0 <= x<= 1)`?
I tried this but `FunctionRange` does not accept a domain like this.

```
FunctionRange[x/(-1 + 2 x), x, y, (0 <= x<= 1)]
```

EDIT:
I wrongly wrote it as "function range of the function". Actually I means the range of the function.

Comment: `(0 <= x<= 1)` is not a domain. From the `FunctionRange` docs, "Possible values for dom are Reals and Complexes. The default is Reals."

Comment: You could use `FindMaximum` and `FindMinimum`..

Comment: @bbgodfrey - to determine range using min and max you need to look at two intervals: `Flatten[Outer[{#2, #1, #2[{x/(-1 + 2 x), #1}, x]} &, {0 <= x < 1/2, 1/2 < x <= 1}, {MaxValue, MinValue}], 1] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &`

Comment: What do you mean by *"How can I function range of the function..."*? Is something missing? For example, *"How can I find the function range of the function..."*? Or something else? Preferably, please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/262383/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `{f, constraints}` as the first argument of [`FunctionRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange.html):

[image]

```
FunctionRange[{x/(-1 + 2 x), 0 <= x <= 1}, x, y]
```

> ```
> y <= 0 || y >= 1
> ```